# ReactJs: onClick is preemtively called

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have 2 onClick functions

```
function VisitGallery(name) {
  const history = useHistory();
  console.log("visitgallery", name)
  history.push("/gallery")
}

function App() {
  const accesstoken = "******************"
  const [viewport, setviewport] = React.useState({
    latitude: ******
    longitude: *******
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    zoom: 11
  })

  const [details, setdetails] = React.useState([
  ])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const db = firebase.firestore()
      const data = await db.collection("data").get()
      setdetails(data.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  const [selectedpark, useselectedpark] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const listener = e => {
      if (e.key === "Escape") {
        useselectedpark(null);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", listener)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", listener)
    }
  }, [])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactMapGl {...viewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={accesstoken}
        mapStyle="mapbox://**************"
        onViewportChange={viewport => {
          setviewport(viewport)
        }}>

        {details.map((details) =>
          <Marker key={details.name} latitude={details.lat} longitude={details.long}>

            <button class="marker-btn" onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              useselectedpark(details);
            }}>
              <img src={icon} alt="icon" className="navbar-brand" />
            </button>

          </Marker>

        )}

        {selectedpark ?
          (<Popup
            latitude={selectedpark.lat}
            longitude={selectedpark.long}
            onClose={() => {
              useselectedpark(null);
            }}
          >
            <div>

              <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{selectedpark.name}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>
                    {selectedpark.postalcode}
                  </Card.Text>
                  <Button variant="primary" onClick = VisitGallery() >Visit Gallery</Button>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </div>
          </Popup>)
          : null}
        {
          console.log("in render", details)
        }

      </ReactMapGl>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The outer onClick is assigned when the marker is first created, and when it is clicked the useselectedpark function is called, details is then assigned to selectedpark.

The inner onClick is assigned to the function VisitGallery(). When the inner onClick is triggered, i want to navigate to another page, hence the history.push().

Ideally, what i want for it to happen is, when the outer onClick is triggered, the cardview shows, and i have an option to visit the next page, which can be triggered by an onClick within the card. **However**, what is happening right now is both the onClicks are triggered when i click on the thumbnail. How do i fix it such that it is how i want it to be ideally?

ps: do let me know if my explanation is confusing and i will edit it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your second onClick into a callback function?

```
<Button variant="primary" onClick='()=>{ VisitGallery() }' >Visit Gallery</Button>
```

So that it doesn't automatically invoke the function until the click is triggered.